# Outgoing Email issues with different ports

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am writing an application which sends emails based on the entered email address and password. I am a bit new to sending Emails from applications.
I wanted to know how do i handle the different port numbers that are there. For example gmail needs 587 while yahoo needs 465 and rediff needs 25.
Isnt there a single solution for all this?
Also this sounds pretty stupid but do SMTP server addresses or ports change over time?

Comment: Please read this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP#Ports

Answer (score 1):

The Ports could change if the admins at vendor side (google, yahoo, etc.) intend to change their policies. So AFAIK there isnt any unified solution for this, rather have a XML doc of this setting and use it in your app.

Comment: i would still need to specify the port number and all other credentials right? How can an XML doc help me? can you please cite an example or a link.

Comment: Yes, ports and other credential info still has to be submitted. 
I was jst asnwering to your question "Also this sounds pretty stupid but do SMTP server addresses or ports change over time?"

So having this different ports, credentials info in a XML file gives you flexibility of dynamic code meaning you dont have to update your code if tomorrow port changes or some other setting changes from vendor.

Comment: dynamically?? amazing, that sounds like the solution for me :D can you give me a link or something? i havnt worked with XML much? just basic android UI stuff!!

Comment: This could be your XML structure (rough idea) <settings> <gmail> <port>512</port> <SSL>1</SSL> </gmail> <yahoo> <port>123</port> <SSL>0</SSL> </yahoo> </settings> how to read this XML? well please refer to MSDN. If tis is a solution ur luking for, then dont forget to upvote/accept :) thnx

Comment: but i could still do the same using the systems.net.mail class in C# any particular reason why i should use XML? dynamic is possible using C# code too. I could use multiple ifs isnt it?

Comment: Please read the comment again, what if the settings changes often?? How many times you shall edit your code? Plus ifs or switch isnt good at all. You have to write smart code and not just plain code. Small code is always good.

Comment: Alright that is correct. Lesser the better. I havent used XML in C# other that what is already there in the settings file (properties.settings.default) so should I google embedding XML in C#? or is there any other specific name for it?

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient allows you to pass in the port with the constructor.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.google.com:587");
client.Send("bob@bob.com", "jim@jim.com", "Subject", "Test Message");
```

Just modify your "host" string in the constructor based on which you are using.  Generally mail services will use non-standard SMTP ports to prevent abuse / penetration attacks etc.

Comment: Yes.  SMTP non-encrypted standard port is 25.  Most new-age mail services will require SSL encryption for SMTP, so they use the non-standard port to differentiate.  Much like port 80 and 443 for http.

Comment: and for the server address, do they tend to change? as in today it is smtp.gmail.com and then somewhere down the line theyll change it to something else?

Comment: Upon further research, it looks like those ARE standard ports, just different standards :)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTPS

Comment: no, addresses won't change.  Ports won't change either.  It's just which "Standard" port are they using.

Answer (score 0):

Have been using something like this a one point solution for your problem.

```
public static bool SendEmail(MailMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        // call the full overload of if GetSMTPClient you want to override the default settings
        using (SmtpClient smtp = GetSMTPClient(true))
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
        return false;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the default SMTP Client (Gmail here)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="isSetAtWebConfig">Has all the settings been specified at web.config</param>
/// <returns>Gets the default SMTP Client</returns>
public static SmtpClient GetSMTPClient(bool isSetAtWebConfig)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client;
        if (isSetAtWebConfig)
        {
            client = new SmtpClient();
        }
        else
        {
            client = GetSMTPClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587, true,
                SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network, false,
                "someone@gmail.com", "somepass");
        }
        return client;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
        throw;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the SMTP Client with custom settings default settings
/// </summary>
/// <param name="host">SMTP Host</param>
/// <param name="port">SMTP Port</param>
/// <param name="enableSSL">Has SMTP enabled SSL</param>
/// <param name="delieveryMethod">SMTP Delivery Method</param>
/// <param name="useDefaultCredentials">Is SMTP using Default Credentials</param>
/// <param name="fromAddress">SMTP Client UserName</param>
/// <param name="fromPassword">SMTP Client Password</param>
/// <returns>Gets the new custom created SMTP Client</returns>
public static SmtpClient GetSMTPClient(string host, int port, 
    bool enableSSL, SmtpDeliveryMethod delieveryMethod, 
    bool useDefaultCredentials, 
    string fromAddress, string fromPassword)
{
    try
    {
        return new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = host,
            Port = port,
            EnableSsl = enableSSL,
            DeliveryMethod = delieveryMethod,
            UseDefaultCredentials = useDefaultCredentials,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword)
        };
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is similar to the code i use but my question is totally different. What if you don not know from where the email is going to come? a user (in my case) can send an email from any email address of his choice.

Comment: make a small provision for adding domain at the settings or check if email.Contains("gmail") and then set the host accordingly. no way you can do a one size fits all approach here. the hosts will surely be different

Comment: ya true. i could us multiple if's but was thinking if there is a better approach